# How to display different value in struts 2 select

Tags: select, struts2

I want to know how to display a different value in struts 2 select.
eg: i want to put Jan,Feb as month where the value should pass 1,2 respectively.

if anybody aware of this please let me know 
thank you.

Answer (score 3):

See the following example (from the Struts 2.1.8 API doc) :

```
<s:select label="Months"
        name="months"
        headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Month"
        list="#{'01':'Jan', '02':'Feb', [...]}"
        value="selectedMonth"
        required="true"
 />
```

The list attribute contains a map where the key is the value that will be sent and the value is the value that will be displayed.

Of course, months are static, but you could use a list of domain objects or whatever beans you need. In this case the list should be stored, typically as a field of your action class. Then you will refer to the list or map :

```
 <s:select label="User"
        name="users"
        headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select User"
        list="users"
        value="selectedUser"
        required="true"
 />
```

In this case your action will contain a map with the usernames and their ids and a getter for it : `getUsers()`.

If the getUsers() method of your action returns a list of User objects, and the User class has at least (let's assume) the `id` and `username` fields, you will have to specify which field to use for value to be passed and which field to use for display in the select. This is done with the `listKey` and `listValue` attributes of the select tag :

```
 <s:select label="User"
        name="users"
        headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select User"
        list="users"
        listKey="id"
        listValue="username"
        value="selectedUser"
        required="true"
 />
```